# Coercing Date Columns in Pandas with null values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading Excel files and need to properly handle dates when reading them. Oftentimes columns will be sparsely populated with dates, and the rest will be blanks. If I read this, it is always read as an `object` dtype. I'm wanting to correctly change these to `datetime64[ns]`, while at the same time not incorrectly converting actual numeric columns.

```
d = {1: {'DateCol': '02/01/2014', 'NotDateCol': 12457}, 2: {'DateCol': np.nan, 'NotDateCol': 45677}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
In [96]: df.dtypes
Out[96]: 
NotDateCol     int64
DateCol       object
dtype: object
```

Ok so if you look at this, you can clearly see DateCol is a Date:

```
  NotDateCol     DateCol
1      12457  02/01/2014
2      45677         NaN
```

Now I need some intelligent way to convert date columns to dates, **without knowing the header names, or the types beforehand**

Trying to just use to_datetime coerces the integers to dates, as so:

```
In [97]: for col in df.columns:
    df[col]  = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
   ....:     

In [98]: df
Out[98]: 
                     NotDateCol    DateCol
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000012457 2014-02-01
2 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000045677        NaT

In [99]: df.dtypes
Out[99]: 
NotDateCol    datetime64[ns]
DateCol       datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Is there any decently intelligent way to get this to work, that will correctly pick out Datetime-like columns and convert them, while not converting numbers to 1970-01-01?

Comment: so how would you identify a date? with a pattern with '/' ?

Comment: have you tried `df.convert_objects()` after loading?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, A date should be something that is obvious. Basically a non-integer that can be coerced to a date in Pandas. Almost like I'm saying "Pandas use your normal date coercion, except integers are not dates"

Comment: @JoeCondron Yep, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to coerce it. According to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.convert_objects.html#pandas.Series.convert_objects):

> **convert_dates :** boolean, default True
>
> If True, convert to date where
>   possible. If ‘coerce’, force conversion, with unconvertible values
>   becoming NaT.

The `convert_ints` flag is False by default, so in this case:

```
In [51]:
d = {1: {'DateCol': '02/01/2014', 'NotDateCol': 12457}, 2: {'DateCol': np.nan, 'NotDateCol': 45677}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index').convert_objects(convert_dates='coerce')

In [52]:
df.dtypes

Out[52]:
NotDateCol             int64
DateCol       datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```